# Java script not running on webbrowser in WP8 HTML app

Tags: webbrowser-control, windows-phone

I am developing the `WP HTML5` app. I've set of HTMLs, js and css created for it.

The IsScriptEnabled flag is set to true, before I Navigate to the HTML page added as project asset.

The js is not getting executed from the index.html page, I am navigating to. When trued, the same js execution is happening properly on iOS and Android.

What can be the possible reasons for the same.

Anything that has to be done (apart from enabling script) before navigating to the page? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The `IsScriptEnabled` flag does not enable/disable JS, but it enables JS to call out to the app and vice versa.

So, I assume you have some JS in the OnLoad of the page you are navigating to. If you replace your code with a simple `document.writeLine("test")`, does that work? If it does work I'd assume that IE's JS engine is (once again) not compliant.

You could also listen to [window.onError](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/better-error-handling-with-window-onerror/)